# $\sum_{r=1}^\infty r^{-r}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

is there any way to analytically find out at what value the summation of $r^{-r}$ from $r=1$ to infinity converges ?
it seems to be around 1.291 if i actually calculate it

Comment: This series converges *extremely rapidly*. I don't know if there is a closed form solution, but summing the first $100$ terms, say, would be correct to thousands of digits.

Comment: @davidlowryduda it would be correct to around 200 digits

Comment: What does "analytical" mean here. The actual sum gives an analytical solution, as I would define it.